# Is only one release is needed in my Objective C code?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa, memory-management

For some reason I can't use `arc`, so in my code below..

**Foo.h**

```
@interface Foo : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString * string;

@end
```

**Foo.m**

```
@implementation Foo

@synthesize string=_string;

- (void) bar {
    self.string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"test1"];
    self.string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"test2"];
}

-(void) dealloc
{
    [_string release];

    [super dealloc];
}
@end
```

The `bar` method might not always be called, or they can be called multitime.

Is only one `release` in the `dealloc` is all needed?

Comment: i wonder stringWithFormat doesn't return a string in autorelease mode?

Comment: Why are you using `stringWithFormat` here? Those are not format strings. I know the point here is to ask about memory management but still, this indicates you don't understand how to use strings. Just use `self.string = @"some text";`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, since you are using properties so setter method will take care of releasing memory allocation.It will allocate memory as follows:

```
-(void)setValue:(NSString *)strValue
{
   if(string)
   {
     [string release];
     string = nil;
   }
   string = [strValue copy];
}
```

Comment: Actually no, not precisely. This will fail if you set the same object twice and it only has one reference.

Comment: @H2CO3 : please clear my doubt.. "stringWithFormat return a string in autorelease mode"..is this correct or not?

Answer (score 2):

> Is only one release in the dealloc is all needed?

Yes.

Explanation: the setter method releases the old object that was assigned to the property and retains the new one.

Comment: I'd have answered the opposite: you don't want to be calling methods on a partially dealloc'd class, especially when allowing for potential subclasses and KVO observers.

Comment: @Tommy No. The memory management of properties is internal and not to be relied upon in actual code. Until an object hasn't called `[super dealloc];`, accessing it is valid. If the getters and setters do unexpected things or rely on something that is out of their scope, that's the reuslt of a badly designed code.

Comment: Apple explicitly advises [Don’t Use Accessor Methods in Initializer Methods and dealloc](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmPractical.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004447-SW6).

Comment: @H2CO3, the problem isn't that getters and setters might be doing something 'out of their scope' - any other object could be observing this object's `string` property. When it (anyOtherObject) receives a KVO notification it should be able to assume that the object it is observing isn't half-way through its -dealloc method.

Comment: @hooleyhoop I do, but I think there's a reason `UIView` and `UIViewController` are two separate classes. MVC doesn't mean one is permitted to violate encapsulation.